# Migrating from Filter to Interceptor results in 403 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application i'm handling JWTs with the following `Filter`:

(irrelevant code is omitted for brevity)

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // processing the JWT from the request

        Authentication auth =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, roles);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, but i would like to migrate this functionality to an interceptor instead, so i simply added the same logic to a `HandlerInterceptor`:

```
@Component
public class JwtInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {

        // processing the JWT from the request

        Authentication auth =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, roles);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        return true;
    }
}
```

But in this case, i always receive 403 Forbidden response for my requests.

I've debugged the `JwtInterceptor` and it seems to be working properly.

`preHandle()` is fully executed, `setAuthentication()` is called with the correct `auth` parameter and the function returns `true`.

So i guess the `Authentication` gets "lost" after the execution of this interceptor, but i cannot figure out why and at this point i don't really know how to debug further.

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to solve this (or even just how to figure out what the problem might be).

Comment: You should really be using a filter and integrate it with the Spring Security filter chain. An interceptor won't work as that executes after the Spring Security filter which does the authentication checks.

Comment: @M.Deinum My problem is `@ResponseStatus` annotations on my custom `Exception` classes are ignored when they're being thrown from a `Filter`, but work from a `HandlerInterceptor`, that's why i was trying to use the latter instead. I guess i'll go back to using a `Filter` then and set the response status manually.